Filtering matched collection based on numerous options Laravel
$vehicle = collect([
    'brand' => 'Ford',
    'model' => 'F-150',
    'color' => 'black'

]);

Every collection will have a singular vehicle with these options. However, not every option will be used to search if it does not contain certain options. Every result will return a singular result.
So far I have:
$vehicleIndex = \App\Models\VehicleIndex::with([
    'brand' => fn ($query) => $query->where('brad', $vehicle->get('brad')),
    'model' => fn ($query) => $query->where('model', $vehicle->get('model')),
    'color' => fn ($query) => $query->where('color', $vehicle->get('color')),
])->get();

The idea is the vehicleIndex returns back a unique filter that was configured to search for vehicles. So the first collection can correctly match on every option in the index. However, that may not be the case everytime.
So, one index option could be:
a black Ford F-150
That would return the results with no issues.
But if there is also a index option for:
F-150
then the above query will return two results. But I am not sure the best way to filter it down to only one result
Take this example:
$vehicle = collect([
    'brand' => 'Toyota',
    'model' => 'F-150',
    'color' => 'green'

]);

The index option should only return F-150. However, the query will pick both of them up since F-150 is being returned in both. However, brand would be null since it doesn't match.
What is the best way to filter out options that do not match in a collection when I have to filter on every relationship?

are you trying to say that if no result is found for all 3 filters, a match should be attempted on less filters?
